# How to use Dualhead2Go with HDMI port

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, video-conversion

I have a Dualhead2Go Digital Edition and my computer just have a HDMI port so I buy a HDMI to VGA converter. But on the full resolution of 3840x1200 to support 2 monitors with 1920x1200 each, it does not work.

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this. I tried to find some converter recommended by Matrox but did not find anything. Any help will be very useful.

Comment: Your not going to be able to run at the higher resolution if you continue to use VGA

Comment: http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/ Has DVI-D ports not VGA, going to VGA to DVI-D requires an active adapter and that adapter is likely to interfere with your Mattox device

Comment: But Matrox sell the device with VGA ports as input http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital/.

Comment: With the orginal HDMI to VGA converter of my Asus computer it works perfecly, but after like 2 months working it just burn and this is already the secound time that happens.